# React – The elements of array received from backend has no paramteres

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-mvc, fetch-api

I am using React + C# for my website. I'm trying to get some data from database, but seem to have some troubles. Here's the function in my controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("GetUsersListByRoleAsync")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserSimple>>> GetUsersListByRoleAsync(int roleId)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<UserSimple> result = await aRepo.GetUsersListByRoleAsync(roleId);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`UserSimple` class:

```cs
public class UserSimple
{
    int Id_User { get; set; }
    string DomainName { get; set; }
}
```

Function in the frontend `DbHandler`:

```js
async GetUsersListByRoleAsync(roleId: number): Promise<UserSimple[]> {
    const resp = await fetch(`api/Administration/GetUsersListByRoleAsync?roleId=${roleId}`, {credentials: "include"})

    if (resp.status >= 400)
        throw new Error(`[AdministrationDbHandler]: ${await resp.text()}`)

    const usersList = await resp.json() as UserSimple[]
    return usersList
}
```

`UserSimple` type in the frontend:

```js
export type UserSimple = {
    id_User: number
    domainName: string
}
```

The thing is, while debugging in the backend everything is great, but in the frontend, `resp.json() as UserSimple[]` returns the following:

```
0: {}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

So, it has the needed amount of elements, but they're empty. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties in class `UserSimple` should be public:

```
public class UserSimple
{
    public int Id_User { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: omg, you're so right. I was very inattentive, thank you